# Clone repo from github website opens Visual Studio 2015 instead of 2017

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Steps

1. Clone a github repository from the github website.
2. Choose Open in Visual Studio
3. Answer Yes to 'Did you mean to switch applications'

[image]

Expected result:

- Opens in Visual Studio 2017

Actual result:

- Opens in Visual Studio 2015

Context:

- Windows 10 anniversary edition
- Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 installed in that order
- Tested in Edge

Comment: It is very likely to be a Github/Edge issue, which you should report to their feedback sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now using Visual Studio version 2017.3.5 and this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Check your default programs. Maybe it's set to open everything Visual Studio 2015? For checking this you have two ways:

1. Inside Windows 10 go to Settings > System > Default Apps and check if Visual Studio 2015 is set to open any project by default.
2. Go to Control Panel (Make sure it's not set on Category view) > Default programs > Set Default Programs

This should work, I didn't try it but if it helps, great.